# How to expand output of embedding layer in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I have the following network:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(400000, 100, weights=[emb], input_length=12, trainable=False))

model.add(Conv2D(256,(2,2),activation='relu'))
```

the output from the embedding layer is of shape (batchSize, 12, 100). The conv2D layer requires an input of shape (batchSize, filter, 12, 100), and I get the following error:

```
 Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3
```

So, how can I expand the output from the embedding layer to make it proper for the Conv2D layer?

I'm using Keras with Tensorflow as the back end.

Comment: Replace your Conv2d with Conv1D. Expand dimension is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to add another dimension with the following piece of code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(400000, 100, weights=[emb], input_length=12, trainable=False))
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: expand_dims(x, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(256,(2,2),activation='relu'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding a reshape Layer should be the way to go https://keras.io/layers/core/#reshape
Depending on the concrete situation Conv1D cold although work.

Comment: reshape changes the data itself, but I need to add another dimension with length 1!!

Comment: It seems that you solved your problem (I totally forgot about lambda layers), but is there a reason not to use Conv1D?

Comment: I need a 2D kernel (window) to slide over the data, Conv1D convolves over only one dimension.